# why doesn't dask parallelize this workflow?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I have 2 very simple functions:

```
import time

def sleepy(a=1):
    time.sleep(a)
    print(a)

def ending(*args):
    print(args)
    print('finished')
```

I also have a dask workflow that uses these functions:

```
workflow = {'task_0': (sleepy, 1), 
            'task_1': (sleepy, 2), 
            'task_2': (sleepy, 3), 
            'ending': (ending, 'task_0', 'task_1', 'task_2')}
```

This workflow can be visualized like this:

[image: dask.visualize(workflow)]

`sleepy`, `sleepy`, `sleepy`, are supposed to be run in parallel, but they aren't.

I wait for 1 second and it prints 1 from `sleepy()`, then I wait 2 seconds and it prints 2, then I wait 3 more seconds and it prints 3:

```
1
2
3
(None, None, None)
finished
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could achieve it reading the very first example on [dask-tutorial](https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial).

Comment: @user32185 Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would code your workflow, and the sleep operations do indeed occur in parallel

```
import dask.delayed
import time

@dask.delayed
def sleepy(a=1):
    time.sleep(a)
    print(a)

@dask.delayed
def ending(*args):
    print(args)
    print('finished')

d = ending(*[sleepy(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]])
d.compute()
```

Note that the `@` decorator is only syntactic niceness, you can also do `dask.delayed(sleepy)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `dask.get(` to `dask.threaded.get(` fixed my problem but I also really liked mdurant's answer.